Is it possible to write multiple dimensions from a las file to a zarr file variables using PDAL?
I'm using PDAL Python to process las files. I'm able to write the output to zarr but I cant figure out how to write all dimensions of the array to the zarr file as separate variables. I have figured out how to write particular dimensions, such as Z or Intensity. But I cant figure out how to write a number of them at once.
Below is my code. The example below I have selected the Intensity dimension to write instead of Z (default). The gdalopts option seems to have no effect.
%%time

# Loop through each LAS file and process it
for las_file in las_files:
    base_name = os.path.basename(las_file)
    base_no_ext = os.path.splitext(base_name)[0]
    output_file = base_no_ext + '.zarr'
    
    # pdal pipeline
    stage_1 = pdal.Reader.las(
        filename=las_file
    )

    stage_2 = pdal.Filter.sort(dimension="X")
    
    # Define options for the GDAL writer
    gdal_options = {
        'ARRAY_NAME': 'Intensity'
    }
    
    # pdal Writer with GDAL options
    stage_3 = pdal.Writer.gdal(
        gdaldriver='zarr',
        output_type='mean',
        resolution=1.0,
        filename='zarr/' + output_file,
        data_type='Float32',
        gdalopts=gdal_options,
        dimension='Intensity'
    )
    
    # Build and execute the PDAL pipeline
    pipeline = pdal.Pipeline([stage_1, stage_2, stage_3])
    pipeline.execute()


